# Android -Multiple information between fragments onClick

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-bundle

I've read a lot but I didn't find the issue.
I'm displaying my News on a `ListFragment` and I have a `onListItemClick`that is working properly according the item clicked but I'm trying to send some variables to another fragment (like a single fragment where displays the information) but it's returning null (no information on fragment B)

My `ListFragment` `onListItemClick`:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    news = newss.get(position);
    SingleNewsFragment singleNewsFragment = new SingleNewsFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(KEY_ID, news.getPark_id());
    bundle.putString(KEY_DATE, news.getDate());
    bundle.putString(KEY_TITLE, news.getTitle());
    bundle.putString(KEY_DESC, news.getDescription());
    singleNewsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, singleNewsFragment, null)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}`
```

My Single News Fragment `onCreate`:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
String id = bundle.getString(KEY_ID);
String date = bundle.getString(KEY_DATE);
String title = bundle.getString(KEY_TITLE);
String description = bundle.getString(KEY_DESC);
```

Basically the strings are not being sent to the fragment B.

Thank you

Comment: Code looks ok, maybe KEY_ID... constants are different in fragment?

Comment: @MaciejSikora that was epic... since I was catching the xml variables and not the sqlite....

Comment: so i found the issue?

Comment: @MaciejSikora yes, thank you!

Comment: I add answer if so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks ok so problem might be with identificators KEY_ID and others. Maybe ids not match in Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply get the data by -

String id =getArguments().getString("whatever yo set in your bundle");

write in onCreateView()